# How to send a pointer to uint_32 from Java in JNA?

Tags: java, c, pointers, struct, jna

I have the following struct in C:

```
struct m{
   unit32_t *p; // array of uint32_t
};
```

And the following function:

```
void print(struct *m);
```

How can I call this method with JNA and represent the structure in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nominally you'd do this:

```
public interface MyLib extends Library {
    class MyStruct extends Structure {
        public Pointer p;
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("p");
        }
    }
    void print(MyStruct s);
}

MyLib lib = Native.loadLibrary("mylib", MyLib.class);
MyStruct s = new MyStruct();
s.p = new Memory(length * 4);
lib.print(s);
```